# devise current_user showing up nil when the method is index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I checked my routes, I do not have anything in routes that says only or except or anything.  If I call the method show it current_user is there. But if I define the method as index.  I can't get the current user. This is for an API documentation i wanted to display the current users info.

```
  def index
    @user  = current_user
    @pages = Page.all
  end
```

Comment: There is no reason for this is be the case with Devise by default.  You must have a before action or something that is overriding the `current_user` method.  Have you defined `current_user` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Just to confirm you have verified that the current_user is set before going to index correct? Is there anyway the user is not logged in when going to index, perhaps they were just logged out before going there?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Was very stupid. I had called the view show.html.erb. Forgot to rename it to index. Thank you!